# Having a strange JSON Parsing issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I know there have been lots of JSON parsing questions posted before, none of them have helped me.

I am sending JSON back to my page from PHP via ajax. According to JSONLint.com I am using valid JSON.

My issue is everytime I go to access properties of my object they come back as undefined. I `console.log` the json object and it comes out fine. I am confused!

### PHP

```
  $returnData[] = array("trainingAccess" => "$trainingAccess", 
    "destinationUrl" => "$destinationUrl", "errorMessage" => "$errorMessage");  

  echo json_encode($returnData);
```

### JS

```
      $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "submit_login.php",
        data: {
          userName: $("#userName").val(),
          password: $("#password").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(data);

          console.log(obj);//Works
          alert(obj.destinationURL);//Doesn't work.
        }
```

### Solution

I was making an array of arrays in PHP.

`$returnData = array("trainingAccess" => "$trainingAccess", 
        "destinationUrl" => "$destinationUrl", "errorMessage" => "$errorMessage");`

Comment: try obj.data.destinationURL or obj.data[0].destinationURL depending on your object

Comment: What does `console.log(obj);//Works` give you? *side note* add `dataType: "json"` and remove `JSON.parse`

Comment: `[Object]
0: Object
destinationUrl: "myurl.php"
errorMessage: ""
trainingAccess: "a|b|c|d"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]`

Comment: please enclose it in `` or edit your post with it and mark it as code for readability.

Comment: Got it figured out. `obj[0].destinationURL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ajax` method will guess the data type of the result, and might parse it if it comes with the right content type.

Specify the data type so that you are sure what's happening, then you know that the data is already parsed for you:

```
  $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: "submit_login.php",
    data: {
      userName: $("#userName").val(),
      password: $("#password").val()
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      alert(data[0].destinationUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
alert(obj[0].destinationUrl);
```

upper lower case issue.

Edited to show the actual solution for others to see...

Comment: undefined still. Thanks though!